# Finding date locations in 100K plus row Spreadsheet Efficiency

Tags: vba, excel

Had some good help from some great folks yesterday.  I extrapolated on it and wanted to ask if anyone knew of more efficient ways to do this.  Finding the start date locations are very efficient as it's nearly 3 lines of code, but the finding the end dates is a bit harder because it finds the first instance of the date and then iterates over a loop until it reaches the end, which is inefficient for obvious reasons.  These are two separate functions (one to find the start rows of the date and one to find the last row of the end date.  Anyone have any ideas? Code below

NOTE: Start date is not the same as end date...Generally a month apart (2/1/14) (2/28/14)

There's confusion as to what my start dates and end dates are.  Apologies.  dateToAnalyze is the parameter that is receiving the date from the main sub.  The first function "GetStartLocations" find the start date that is passed to it in the spreadsheet.  To remain consistent with the dates I put up top.  The start date (2/1/14) would be passed to the GetStartLocations and the end date (2/28/14) would be passed to the GetEndLocations.

These functions are merely meant to ultimately find the row location of the date it's passed.  If it doesn't find the date...rather than erroring...it increments forward to find the next closest date.  That works great for the GetStartLocations function, but not so great for the end location because it could end up incrementing well past the end date needed.

```
Public Function GetStartLocations(dateToAnalyze As Range, masterList As Worksheet) As Long

Dim finderCounter As Integer
Dim finder As Range
finderCounter = 0

Do
    Set finder = masterList.Range("A:A").Find(dateToAnalyze.Value + finderCounter, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    finderCounter = finderCounter + 1

Loop Until Not finder Is Nothing

GetStartLocations = finder.Row

End Function

Public Function GetEndLocations(dateToAnalyze As Range, masterList As Worksheet) As Long

'Seperate function for End location required since the find function finds the first instance of date being searched

Dim finderCounter As Integer
Dim finder As Range
Dim location As Long
finderCounter = 0

'Finds initial date in master list...If date is not found..increments upwards until it finds next nearest date sucessfully
Do
    Set finder = masterList.Range("A:A").Find(dateToAnalyze.Value + finderCounter, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    finderCounter = finderCounter + 1

Loop Until Not finder Is Nothing
    location = finder.Row

Do
DoEvents
    location = location + 1

Loop Until Range("A" & location).Value <> Range("A" & (location + 1)).Value

GetEndLocations = location

End Function
```

Comment: try masterlist.range("A:A").rows(GetStartLocations(x,y) & ":" masterlist.rows.count).find.....  or putting the result of the start location and the using it in the same way

Comment: I'll add a note I should have mentioned that the start date is not same as end date.

Comment: perhaps you could add a couple of notes that define **exactly** what a start date and end date is. Your code makes absolutely **no** sense to me. *'Generally a month apart'* is not a description. It is, well... a generalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the end date is simply the last occurrence of the start date use,

```
... SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, After:=masterList.Range("A"&rows.count)
```

... to loop backwards around the worksheet and start at the bottom to look up.

Comment: Simplest and perfectly working solution.  The rows.count portion was throwing me off.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Find may not be the most efficient method to use. Often reading into a variant array or using Worksheetfunction.MATCH can be faster.
For a discussion of the pros and cons of various approaches see
https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/